# Can a Laravel Middleware act as a before and after middleware at the same time?

Tags: laravel, middleware

Do you think it's possible for a Laravel 6 Middleware to act as a before and after middleware at the same time? I don't see any restrictions about that but I can't find any examples.

Comment: I remember this was a question in Laravel Certification exam

Answer (score 1):

Yes ... all middleware can be both (the difference is conceptual). If you do things before the call to `$next($request)` its a before middleware. If you do things after the call to `$next($request)` it is an after middleware. It also can be a 3rd thing, a terminable middleware.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer didn't really provide any answers and instead explained basic middleware, so to sum it up for you a middleware only has one handle method that returns a single variable. So it is impossible to have before and after on the same middleware and you'd need two.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).